# Error when trying to link Box2D on Codeblocks 10.05 running on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, box2d, codeblocks

I'm trying to build a game I made with SDL and Box2D, but I hit a problem when trying to link the Box2D library. I set up the Box2D library as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491007/how-would-i-build-box2d-to-work-in-codeblocks-mingw32windows) but when I try to build the game I get this error:

```
mingw32-g++.exe: \usr\local\lib\libBox2D.so: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: Try CMake GUI. It should show not found libraries, and provide possibility to specify path manually by graphic interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I managed to fix this by changing the project build options.