# Updating Box2D In Code::Blocks Project - <Box2D/Box2D cannot be found>

Tags: c++, box2d, codeblocks

I am trying to update a year-old project for the latest version of Code::Blocks and the MinGW GNU Compiler.  I am pretty new to working with libraries, so a noob answer would be much appreciated!

The project uses .a library files from Box2D.  From my understanding, in order to update the project I need to build the latest version of Box2D which will generate the needed .a files and use those to replace the old project files.  I downloaded the latest Box2D build from [here](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/detail?name=Box2D_v2.2.1.zip) and extracted it to a location outside of the main project.  When I try to build the "HelloWorld.cpp" application, I get the error: 
fatal error: Box2D/Box2D.h: No such file or directory

The file is definitely there, so I think I need to update my project dependencies, but I'm not sure the proper way to do this.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491007/how-would-i-build-box2d-to-work-in-codeblocks-mingw32windows) helped a bit, but I have no experience with cmake or how to properly install it.

Do I just need to fix this dependency error (and how?), or is there a better way to get the new .a files from the latest Box2D source?
Thanks for any help!

EDIT - I am using Windows 7 64-bit. I believe the original project was made on the same OS a year ago.

EDIT2 - Just to make it more clear, the project that Box2D is being used for is for a computer application, not an Andriod or IOS app.

Comment: What OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit, sorry forgot to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to solve your problem is install box2d into system. To do this, copy 'Box2D' directory, which contains headers into C:/MinGW/include, and box2d *.lib (or *.a) file into C:/MinGW/lib. "C:/MinGW" is path, where you installed the MinGW.

p.s. I can mismatch names of directories, it was many time ago when I working with this.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out how to use cmake and it accomplished the same thing and made the file for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me to. Did you check if the folder usr/include/Box2d exists?

Somehow mine wasn't there, and I fixed it by typing

```
sudo apt-get install libbox2d-dev
```

and installing it again.

Hope this helps someone.
bye!